# How to compare string date with time_t in c++?

Tags: c++, datetime

I have string below.

```
std::string _valid = "2014-03-28 16:45:59";

int y1, M1, d1, h1, m1, s1;
sscanf_s(_valid.c_str(), "%d-%d-%d %d:%d:%d", &y1, &M1, &d1, &h1, &m1, &s1);
```

Now, I can get year, month, day and so on...

Now, I have to determine whether that time is earlier than current datetime.

```
time_t now  = time(NULL);
```

But, time_t always returns me the time in unix timestamp.

How can I compare the date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set to struct [tm](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/tm/), then generate [time_t](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/time_t/) by function [mktime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/mktime/). You can compare the value of two time_t directly.

You can also use [SYSTEMTIME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [FILETIME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724284%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from windows.h. Set to SYSTEMTIME then generate FILETIME by function [SystemTimeToFileTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724948%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Compare two FILETIME by function [CompareFileTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724214%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
To compute the distance between two FILETIME, I'm writing the follow ugly code:

```
__int64 duration = ((*(__int64 *)&ft2) - (*(__int64 *)&ft1));
```

Note that SYSTEMTIME has higher resolution than struct tm.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the mktime function. The details are here http://linux.die.net/man/3/mktime, but in a nutshell...

```
#include <time.h>
time_t mktime(struct tm *tm);
```

where the struct tm is defined in time.h as...

```
struct tm
{
  int tm_sec;           /* Seconds. [0-60] (1 leap second) */
  int tm_min;           /* Minutes. [0-59] */
  int tm_hour;          /* Hours.   [0-23] */
  int tm_mday;          /* Day.     [1-31] */
  int tm_mon;           /* Month.   [0-11] */
  int tm_year;          /* Year - 1900.  */
  int tm_wday;          /* Day of week. [0-6] */
  int tm_yday;          /* Days in year.[0-365] */
  int tm_isdst;         /* DST.     [-1/0/1]*/

#ifdef  __USE_BSD
  long int tm_gmtoff;       /* Seconds east of UTC.  */
  __const char *tm_zone;    /* Timezone abbreviation.  */
#else
  long int __tm_gmtoff;     /* Seconds east of UTC.  */
  __const char *__tm_zone;  /* Timezone abbreviation.  */
#endif
};
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Another way to generate the `struct tm`, other than using `sscanf`, is the `strptime` function (the inverse of `strftime`). This is not standard C, but it can read more possible date/time formats.  If your system doesn't have it then you could download an open-source version.